# How to assign multiple users from database to class attributes?

Tags: php, class, orm

I cant figure out how to assign each one user from my database as class attribute and display them. Take a look. For example I have this table in my db:

```
+----+----------+------------+-----------+
| id | username | first_name | last_name |
+----+----------+------------+-----------+
|  1 | guu      |  Guu       | GuuShtein |
|  3 | user1    |  Allan     | Last      |
|  4 | Donny    |  Name      | Last Name |
+----+----------+------------+-----------+
```

And here is the class:

```
class users {

public $db;
private $id;
private $username;
private $first_name;
private $last_name;

public function __construct($db) {
    $this->db=$db;
}

private function find_by_id($id) {
   $record = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=' . $id .' LIMIT 1')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);     
   foreach ($record as $atribute => $value) {
       $this->$atribute = $value;
   } 
}

public function user_nfo($id){
    $this->find_by_id($id);

    $user_nfo = "User id: " . $this->id . "<br />";
    $user_nfo .= "Username: " . $this->username . "<br />";
    $user_nfo .= "User full name: " . $this->first_name . " " . $this->last_name . "<br />";       
    return $user_nfo;
}
}

$users = new mysql_a($db);
echo $users->user_nfo(1);
```

My question is how to write a method, that displays all users one by one? I mean something similar like in my user_nfo function, but just for all records? I tried "foreach" loop with PDOfetchAll, but it just overrides attributes and and displays only last record.

Comment: Use an array instead odd user_info variable.. then you could get all the users from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a new object called user that has all the properties that you want, Like the below.

```
<?php

try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sub_db;charset=UTF-8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo "error";
}

class users {

    public $db;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db=$db;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch all users and return an array of their mapped objects
     *
     * @author Daniel Noel-Davies
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllUsers () {
        $users   = array();

        // Grab an array of each user
        $users = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // Loop through the users
        foreach( $users as $index => $user ) {
            // Replace each row with an object of that user (keeps memory down)
            $users[$index] = new User($user);
        }

        // return our array containing an object of each user
        return $users;
    }

    public function count_row(){
        $count = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $count['COUNT(*)'];
    }

    public function find_by_id($row) { 
       $record = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1 OFFSET ' . $row)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       return $record;
    }   
 }


class user {

    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;

    public function __construct($record){    
           foreach ($record as $atribute => $value) {
               $this->$atribute = $value;
           }
    }
}

// Initiate our users class
$objUsers = new Users;

// Fetch all the users
$users = $objUsers->getAllUsers();

// Loop through them all
foreach ($users as $user) {
    // Using Printf keeps things neater, means you're template is tidier.
    printf(
        '%s<br />
        %s<br />
        %s<br />
        %s<br />',

        $user->id,
        $user->username,
        $user->first_name,
        $user->last_name
    );
}
?>
```

Does this help?

Comment: This is what we call ORM or Object-Relational mapping. Basically, it states that we can create an Object that has the same object-relational structure that the database does.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to "NoelDavies" answer, here is a complete code that I managed to make working for me. In case someone comes of with the same issue:

```
<?php

try {
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sub_db;charset=UTF-8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo "error";
}

class mysql_a {

    public $db;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db=$db;
    }

    public function count_row(){
        $count = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $count['COUNT(*)'];
    }

    public function find_by_id($row) { 
       $record = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1 OFFSET ' . $row)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       return $record;
    }   
 }


class user {

    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;

    public function __construct($record){    
           foreach ($record as $atribute => $value) {
               $this->$atribute = $value;
           }
    }
}


$users = new mysql_a($db);

for ($i = 0; $i < $users->count_row(); $i++) {
    $user = new user($users->find_by_id($i));
    echo $user->id         . "<br />";
    echo $user->username   . "<br />";
    echo $user->first_name . "<br />";
    echo $user->last_name  . "<hr />";
}
?>
```

It counts rows in db and then one by one pulls them out and outputs. I'm sure there is some shorter and more elegant way, but it works fine for me now;] Thanks again "NoelDavies".

Comment: I improved my answer, it includes your latest revision